# DB2 Automatic Initialization and Updating for TIMESTAMP

Tags: sql, database, database-design, db2

I would like to append two timestamp columns to an existing table. 
CREATED_TSTMP would be populated with the current timestamp when a record is inserted and LAST_UPD_TSTMP would be updated automatically when a record in the table gets updated.

**I would like to do this without having to modify existing queries.**

I have the following DDL statements:

```
ALTER TABLE XXX ADD CREATED_TSTMP TIMESTAMP NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT CURRENT TIMESTAMP ;
alter table XXX add column LAST_UPD_TSTMP timestamp not null generated by default for each row on update as row change timestamp ;
```

However once the columns are appended, this will cause an existing query with the following syntax:

```
INSERT INTO XXX VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

to fail with

> The number of values assigned is not the same as the number of
>   specified or implied columns or variables..

Is there any way around this problem without having to inspect all of the existing queries (there are hundreds of them...)

Comment: Generally speaking, you shouldn't include the type in column names - it's the "bad" form of Hungarian notation.  In particular, if the type changes, things can get.... strange.  Here, you should likely be using something like `created_At` and `last_updated_at` (you also shouldn't be abbreviating if you don't need to).

Comment: Good points, thanks :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add the `IMPLICITLY HIDDEN` option when creating the columns, they will be ignored by the SQL statements *unless* you explicitly mention these columns.

PS. I'm assuming you are on a sufficiently recent version of DB2, because of your using `row change timestamp`. To avoid ambiguity, you should indicate the DB2 version and platform in question.

Comment: `IMPLICITLY HIDDEN` actually seems like you'd want it for auditing columns like these _anyways_, so....